# Will Garbage collection take care of values of lists of lists

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, garbage-collection

Will Garbage Collection free values of a list, if that list is inside an object extending List, and if that object is inside a Dictionary upon clearing the Dictionary. Or do I have to clear each list?

I hope this does not sound too complicated of a question. I tried reading on how Garbage collection in C# works, and it does seem to say it takes care of everything.(literally), but I would like to make sure.
I also tried finding if someone had the same question, but the questions I found did not involve Dictionaries.

EDIT: So, I re-read information on Garbage Collection and it really does seem that it would take care of it all. Can anyone confirm that I am just being paranoid of memory leaks. Also I know I could test for memory leaks, but why, if someone already has the answer.

Comment: The questions I found also did not involve Garbage Collection.

Comment: Garbage collector takes care of  clearing any objects those moved out of scope ,means has no references to those object. Unless you notice any memory leaks leave it to GC to handle.

Comment: You do not need to clear it. GC will find and free any objects that cannot be traversed in the object graph.

Comment: Ok thank you. It makes sens too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**.

When you clear the items in the dictionary, the reference count for each of those (list) items will decrease by one. For each of those where the reference count is now zero (no other references to it), the object will be eligible for garbage collection. After it has been garbage collected itself, the reference count to each of the underlying items within (the list), will in turn decrease by one, and the same process will repeat.

There may be additional optimizations in the garbage collector to work with the items in a list as a special case, but the conceptual model should remain consistent with the above description.

The normal caveats regarding garbage collection still apply and are more likely to be a source of memory leaks. For example, if the items in the list are holding on to a resource, like an open database connection (really anything which implements *IDisposable*), you need to make sure that you explicitly call "Dispose" on each item before letting go of the reference.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and sweet answer! ;)

Comment: This is better explained then the Microsoft page itself. thanks